# Best format to export to using MVC (CSV, XLS, PDF, etc...)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

Hi all i've written an mvc application that will display a lot of phone call data to the user in a table with pagination. The amount of data were talking about here is for one months of data, which could be around 950,000 records. The user has asked for the ability to export the data and view it in a "nice" clear format. I am just wondering what would be best format to export this data to as we are talking about a huge amount of data! Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the export format is not really related to the server/client side technology and framework you are using like ASP.NET MVC, WebForms, Windows Forms win client application etc...

the first question you should ask your customer is what he needs to do with the exported data.

if they want to edit or filter/pivot the data, `csv` is probably a good option because they can open these files with excel directly and work with those.

if they simply want to read and archive with also a basic search feature and easy printing, `pdf` could be more appropriate.

in fact to export to `csv` trivial/easy solution is a nested for on the `DataReader`/`DataTable` you get from the database and an append to a StringBuilder, this all can happen server side then you simply stream down to the client the csv content for download or you save it on the server and give a link to it, or you zip it server side and send via email... it all depends on your requirements.

For `PDF` there are plenty of libraries out there to generate those acrobat reader files...

Answer (score 4):

I think the best Format you can use if you want a small file size is `CSV`.
CSV is a good format for things like that. For example Excel can open CSV too.

You can do the following to give the user the possibility for downloading a csv file without creating a physical file on your servers hard disk.

```
public ActionResult DownloadCsv(int id)
{
    //var data = ... // get the data for the id

    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=callData.csv");
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    //write the column names
    Response.Write("Id;PhoneNr");

    //write the data
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        Response.Write(String.Format("{0};{1}", item.Id, item.PhoneNr));
    }

    Response.End();
    return null;
}
```

**hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements. I would use CSV format since it can be easily imported in an Excel spreadsheet by your customer. There are some technical issues that you want to be aware of, such as the size of the data being exported. In an MVC specific implementation I would create an intermediate view, which will display a loading message, then using javascript redirect user to a url which is handled by a Controller Action that will be responsible for getting the data and returning it back to the user. In the action method you should, call your business class that will read your data from database, convert to CSV file, and then zip the contents using ([Zip  format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)). Action method can then return results with [FileStreamResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult.aspx)  back to the user.